# MSMQ is a good choice?

Tags: msmq

I'm doing some test messaging, and so far the MSMQ is the choice, especially for support in Mass Transit.

But there are other options, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ are some examples. Has anyone had problems with MSMQ, you think in comparison with the examples?

It is strange to find documentation on the website of MS over MQMQ, a list of features, etc ... the good part is that it is in windows, it costs nothing, and we have support from Microsoft, but it seems to me a product without much attention from Microsoft, what do you think?

Comment: I have heard people slating MSMQ but I have been using it for years. I have had ONE failure, one time in a production environment in the last five years when the MSMQ service just stalled on a server, but apart from that no other problems.

Answer (score 5):

Main problems that people saw (from my perspective in MSMQ support) were (in no particular order):

1. Inadequate monitoring of servers, letting them run out of disk space or fill up with messages, etc.
2. Insufficient resilience in applications (not using dead letter queues, negative source journaling, etc.)
3. Incorrect permissions set on queues
4. Name resolution issues (incorrect DNS server entries, etc)
5. Microsoft toughening RPC security with each version and making getting access to remote queues progressively harder.

I expect the first 4 are generic to most queuing systems.